# Color code a scatter plot by group with a gradient

Tags: r, plotly, gradient, scatter-plot

I have `XY` data which I'd like to graph using a `scatter` `plot`, with `R`'s `plotly` package.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(30,1,1),rnorm(30,5,1),rnorm(30,9,1)),
                 y=c(rnorm(30,1,1),rnorm(30,5,1),rnorm(30,9,1)),
                 group=c(rep("A",30),rep("B",30),rep("C",30)),score=runif(90,0,1))
```

Each point is assigned to one of three groups (`df$group`) and has a score in the `[0,1]` range.

I'm looking for a way to graph the data such that each group is colored with a different color but the shade of that color (or intensity) reflects the score.

So I thought this would work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

    plot_ly(marker=list(size=10),type='scatter',mode="markers",x=~df$x,y=~df$y,color=~df$score,colors=c("#66C2A5","#FC8D62","#8DA0CB")) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F))
```

But I get:
[image]

If I just color code by `group`:

```
plot_ly(marker=list(size=10),type='scatter',mode="markers",x=~df$x,y=~df$y,color=~df$group,colors=c("#66C2A5","#FC8D62","#8DA0CB")) %>%
      layout(xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F))
```

I get:
[image]

So it looks like it is mixing the `group` colors and the `score` gradient.

What I'm looking for is to have the bottom left group colored in shades of green (say from `gray` to `darkgreen`) that correspond to `score` (low to high), and the same for the two other groups in orange and blue, respectively.

Comment: They're not meant to be related to x and y.  x and y simply separate the points by group (let's say "A" are dogs, "B" are cats, and "C" rats). The score is an orthogonal measurement (e.g. water consumption)

Comment: If I understand you correctly you'd like 3 different colour gradients for the 3 different groups, where the gradient colour encodes the score. I don't think this is possible. There exist some hack-y ways to implement [two colour gradient scales in `ggplot2` (and then probably by extension in `plotly`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347147/using-two-scale-colour-gradients-ggplot2). Why not use different symbols for the group and then one common colour gradient for the scale?

Comment: Symbols will be the alternative if a gradient is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `scales::colour_ramp` you can create the colours yourself with a quick function. I'm not sure how else to get different gradients happening within each group. Note I'm using `df$score = df$x + df$y` here to make the mapping more obvious.

```
make_colour_gradient = function(x, brewer_palette = "Greens") {
    min_x = min(x)
    max_x = max(x)
    range_x = max_x - min_x
    x_scaled = (x - min_x) / range_x

    # Chopping out first colour as it's too light to work well as a
    #   point colour
    colours = scales::brewer_pal("seq", brewer_palette)(5)[2:5]

    colour_vals = scales::colour_ramp(colours)(x_scaled)
    colour_vals
}

df$score = df$x + df$y

df = df %>%
    # Assign a different gradient to each group, these are the names
    #   of different palettes in scales::brewer_pal
    mutate(group_colour = case_when(
        group == "A" ~ "Greens",
        group == "B" ~ "Oranges",
        group == "C" ~ "Purples"
    )) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(point_colour = make_colour_gradient(score, first(group_colour)))


plot_ly(marker=list(size=10),type='scatter',mode="markers",
        x=~df$x,y=~df$y,color=~ I(df$point_colour)) %>%
    hide_colorbar() %>%
    layout(xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),
           yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F))
```

Result:

[image: Scatter plot with colours per group]

This does bring up error messages but they don't seem to be important? Adding a legend to this would probably be tricky.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected;-) Very nice. I didn't think this was possible.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in plotly, however, you could also use the alpha  argument in ggplot and to achieve the same result and then convert the ggplot object to plotly. I know there is also an alpha argument in plotly, however, I found it a little difficult.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
    geom_point(aes(color = group, alpha = score), size = 3)+
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#66C2A5","#FC8D62","#8DA0CB"))+
    scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.3,1))+
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
gp <- ggplotly(g)
gp
```

[image]

I couldn't get the legend to format nicely with plotly, however in ggplot, we can keep the legend (omit the `legend.position = "none"`) and we get the following:
[image]

You can also increase the number of different shades using the `breaks` argument in `scale_alpha_continuous`.