# Plot background map from tiff file and add additional points

Tags: r, ggplot2, tiff, rastervis

How do I plot a background map from a .tif file and then add points on top of the map from a different dataframe? Since there are quite a lot of points I would also like to add a second colour gradient for improved visibility, and this is where I am running into the problem. According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347147/using-two-scale-colour-gradients-ggplot2) ggplot prevents this on purpose, but can be worked around using the new_scale_colour function. But this seems to not work unfortunately and also seems a little bit hacky. Are there any better solutions? I also tried to convert the .tif file to a df directly but since its quite big I'd rather not do that.

This is the solution I have right now which uses gplot from rasterVis.

```
gplot(map) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'darkgray') +
  coord_equal()+
  new_scale_color()+
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Location_E, y=Location_N))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="lightblue", high="blue")
```

Looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?