# Indicate three diferent values in a scatterplott using colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend, scatter-plot

I have the following task from my professor:

*Use ggplot2 and create another scatterplot of the variablesact_sm and pop_sm. This time the actors from the US (3), UK (4), and the transnational actors (888) should be indicated with different colors. Make sure there is a legend to the plot. Label the axes reasonably.*

I have the following data.frame named nodes:

```
actor_type actor_ctr actor_pos pop_sm act_sm        str
1            3         4         2    799   1087  1.3604506
102         NA       999        NA     78     90  1.1538462
103         NA       999        NA     78     90  1.1538462
104          3         4         2    441     NA         NA
105          3         4         2   1049    789  0.7521449
106          4        75         1    264    948  3.5909091
107          4        75         1    264    948  3.5909091
4            3         4         2    799   1087  1.3604506
5            3         4         2    799   1087  1.3604506
6            3         4         2    799   1087  1.3604506
7            4         3        NA    158    212  1.3417722
8            4         3        NA    158    212  1.3417722
    ...
```

I want to create a scatter plot from the values of act_sm and pop_sm in which I want to indicate actor_ctr 3, 4 and 888 with different colored dots each - all the other values from actor_ctr should have one color. I have tried it like that but it is not working:

```
nodes%>% filter(nodes, actor_ctr%in% c(3,4,888)%>%
    ggplot(nodes, aes(act_sm, pop_sm))+ 
        geom_point(aes(x= act_sm, y= pop_sm, colour = actor_ctr), size=2)
```

Furthermore I do not know how to insert a legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems with your code.

1. Missing a close-paren after `filter(...c()`.
2. Either use `nodes %>% filter(actor_ctr...)` or `filter(nodes, actor_ctr...)`, not both.
3. Don't reference `nodes` in the call to `ggplot`. There are times when you can (and should) reference an external dataframe in ggplot layers, this is not one of them. Here's what is actually being interpreted:

   ```r
   nodes %>%
     filter(actor_ctr %in% c(3,4,888)) %>%
     ggplot(data = ., mapping = nodes, aes(act_sm, pop_sm)) +
     geom_point(aes(x= act_sm, y= pop_sm, colour = actor_ctr), size=2)
   ```

   where `.` refers to the 8 rows of data after `filter(...)`, and `nodes` refers to your frame before the pipeline started. While `.` is not formally assigned to a variable, it is still the state of the data at that point in the pipe. Here, it's 8 rows with all of the same columns, but it's not hard to come up with examples where `.` and `origdata` have completely different shape and properties.

   Further, because of the positional args there, `mapping=` should certainly not be your `nodes` dataframe.
4. Your color aesthetic is based on a number, so `ggplot2` is going to *infer* that it is continuous, whereas I believe it is in fact ordinal or categorical (discrete). This can often be fixed using `factor(actor_type)`.

Let's try to fix all of those:

```r
nodes %>%
  filter(actor_ctr %in% c(3, 4, 888)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(act_sm, pop_sm)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = act_sm, y = pop_sm, colour = factor(actor_ctr)), size = 2)
```

[image: ggplot2, discrete color aesthetic]

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to add the rest of the variables (which aren't actor_ctr 3, 4 and 888) as a fourth colour on my scatter plot. How can I do that?

Comment: It's difficult to use multiple variables as different color variables. If you search (in general) for `"r" ggplot2 multiple color scale`, you'll see what I'm talking about. There are plenty of questions on SO for it, and some of them have answers that might be applicable for you. I don't have experience with any, but https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5738083/3358272. Lacking that, if you use `color=interaction(actor_ctr, actor_pos, ...)`, you can get different colors for each *combination* of those variables ... not perfect, but usable nonetheless.